# Pandas groupby / pivot table with custom list as index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe; which I need to groupby **year and then by month**.

After groupby/pivot table; It looks something like this:

```
        abc  xyz
2013 6   80  250
     8   40   -5
2014 1   25   15
     2   60   80
```

I want to present the output in such a way that the missing months are filled to 0; **i.e. each year should have all 12 months**; irrespective of the fact that there is data or not for that month.

If there is no data for that month, we just put 0. For eg:

```
        abc  xyz
2013 6   80  250
     8   40   -5
2014 1   25   15
     2   60   80
     3   0    0
     4   0    0
     ...
     12  0    0
```

How can I achieve this in pandas.

Edit:

The data is below:

```
   year  month abc  xyz
    2013  6     80  250
    2013  8     40   -5
    2014  1     25   15
    2014  2     60   80
```

Code used is below:

```py
pd.pivot_table( df, index = ['year', 'month' ],
                values = ['abc'],
                aggfunc = 'sum'
)
```

OR

```py
df.groupby( ['year', 'month' ] ).sum()
```

Comment: this can be done via pandas's resample functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reindex:

```
df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.get_level_values(0).unique(),
                                       range(1,12+1)]),
           fill_value=0)
```

But it might be more easily done in the previous step, could you share the original data and `pivot` command?

Alternative to do it during the previous phase:

```
(df.pivot_table(columns='year',
                index='month',
                values = ['abc'],
                aggfunc = 'sum',
                fill_value=0
               )
   .reindex(range(1,12+1), fill_value=0)
   .stack(level=-1).swaplevel(axis=0)
)
```

output:

```
            abc
year month     
2013 1        0
2014 1       25
2013 2        0
2014 2       60
2013 3        0
...
```

Comment: Added in the question, thanks!

Comment: @vvv OK, then it is as simple to do as I showed above, I still provided code to do it during the pivoting phase